# Есть ли недосказанность в правиле Розенталя?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, однородные-члены

> ...Старики, отец и тесть, были еще живы.

Данное предложение у Розенталя приводится как пример обособленного приложения («отец и тесть»). Оно, соответственно, выделяется запятыми. Если обратиться к правилу об однородных членах при обобщающих словах у того же Розенталя, мы узнаем, что если однородные члены в середине предложения выступают в качестве приложения, их можно выделить тире с обеих сторон. Про запятые ничего не сказано. Так вот, не кажется ли вам, что это прямая недосказанность в правиле, ведь данный пример как раз-таки иллюстрирует допустимость использования запятых в подобных случаях?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае  мы имеем не то чтобы недосказанность, но недостаток в **систематизации** материала.

Очень часто при решении конкретной задачи приходится обращаться к **различным** разделам и темам.  Если следовать правилам чисто формально, но это довольно утомительно, а иногда и безрезультатно. Поэтому нужно четко выбирать грамматику, видеть **особенности грамматических конструкций.**

Эта задача дается в  § 19. **Обособленные приложения**: Старуха, Тришкина мать, умерла, но старики, отец и тесть, были ещё живы (С.-Щ);

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111

Вы же хотите ее решить по правилу для **обобщенных слов** § 15. Обобщающие слова при однородных членах предложения.

Но это правило удобно применять, если мы имеем однородный ряд членов, **разделенных запятыми.** Такой ряд дополнительными запятыми не обособишь, вот и приходится использовать более сильные знаки препинания.

В нашем же случае два однородных члена связаны союзом И, **запятой между ними нет**, поэтому запятые используются при обособлении. Если обособим тире, то это будет необоснованное вставочное обособление.